# localeCompare em Javascript

Tags: javascript, sortable

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
arr = [
  { name: 'This one', number: '67', codes:['B33', '45']},
  { name: 'Another', number: '003', codes: ['55', 'A47']},
  { name: 'Something', codes:['A33']},
  { name: 'One more', number: '003'},
  { name: 'Anything', number: '67', codes:['233']}
  { name: 'Anything else', number: '67', codes:['33']},
];
```

Preciso colocá-lo, primeiramente, em ordem crescente de `number` e, em seguida, em ordem crescente de `codes`.

O objeto que não possuir `number`, está sendo tratado como `number: ''` e o objeto que não possuir `codes` está sendo tratado como `codes: ''`. `codes` é um array de string. Deve ser comparado como uma string única. Por exemplo: `codes: ['55', 'A47']` deve ser comparado como `codes: '55, A47'`.

Desta forma, desejo que fique na seguinte ordem:

```
 arr = [
      { name: 'Something', codes:['A33']},
      { name: 'One more', number: '003'},
      { name: 'Another', number: '003', codes: ['55', 'A47']},
      { name: 'This one', number: '67', codes:['B33', '45']}
      { name: 'Anything else', number: '67', codes:['33']},
      { name: 'Anything', number: '67', codes:['233']},
    ];
```

Com isso, estou usando o seguinte código:

```
orderArr(arr) {
 return arr.sort((a, b) => {
   const an = a.number || '';
   const bn = b.number || '';
   const ac = (a.codes || []).join('');
   const bc = (b.codes || []).join('');
   return (an + ac).localeCompare(bn + bc);
});
}
```

Entretanto, ele está colocando, por exemplo, `{ name: 'Anything', number: '67', codes:['233']},`, na frente de `{ name: 'Anything else', number: '67', codes:['33']}`.

Imagino que ele não deve fazer comparações de centenas e dezenas em `codes`. Como faço para isso não ocorrer?

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma opção no localeCompare() para comparar numericamente. Se o número for igual ordena-se pelo código. E os códigos ordenam-se primeiro pelas letras e depois pelos números.

```
function orderArr(arr) {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => {
        const an = a.number || '0';
        const bn = b.number || '0';
        const ac = (a.codes || []).join('');
        const bc = (b.codes || []).join('');

        if (an == bn) {
            return /^[0-9]/.test(ac) - /^[0-9]/.test(bc) || ac.localeCompare(bc, undefined, {numeric: true});
        }
        return an.localeCompare(bn, undefined, {numeric: true});
    });
}
```